# Creating Object Python 3 From File

Tags: python, haskell, python-3.x, archlinux, aura.js

Okay, I'm stuck. I have been trying to load a file with a serialized string from Aura's save feature and get into an object to work with it.

The file looks like this:

```
 PkgState {timeOf = SimpleTime {yearOf = 2013, monthOf = February, dayOf = 13, hourOf = 15, minuteOf = 38}, pkgsOf = fromList [("a52dec",[0,7,4,6]),("aalib",[1,4,5,9]),("abs",[2,4,4,1]),("acl",[2,2,51,3]),("acsccid",[1,0,4,1]),("alsa-lib",[1,0,26,1]),("alsa-oss",[1,0,25,1]),("alsa-plugins",[1,0,26,1]),("alsa-utils",[1,0,26,1]),("alsaequal",[0,6,7]),("android-sdk-platform-tools",[16,0,1,2]),("android-udev",[1,6,1]),("anki-beta",[2,0,7,1]),("apache",[2,2,23,1]),("apr",[1,4,6,1]),("apr-util",[1,5,1,1]),("archey",[20121216,1]),("archlinux-keyring",[20130127,1]),("archlinux-themes-slim",[1,2,3]),("aria2",[1,16,3,1]),("asciidoc",[8,6,8,1]),("aspell",[0,60,6,1,1]),("aspell-en",[7,1,2]),("at-spi2-atk",[2,6,2,1]),("at-spi2-core",[2,6,3,1]),("atk",[2,6,0,1]),("attr",[2,4,46,2]),("aura",[1,1,3,0,1]),("autoconf",[2,69,1]),("autofs",[5,0,7,1]),("automake",[1,13,1,1]),("avahi",[0,6,31,5]),("babl",[0,1,10,1]),("bash",[4,2,42,3]),("bc",[1,6,8]),("beecrypt",[4,2,1,5]),("binutils",[2,23,1,3]),("bison",[2,7,1]),("blueman",[1,23,5]),("bluez",[4,101,1]),("bridge-utils",[1,5,1]),("bzip2",[1,0,6,4]),("c-ares",[1,9,1,1]),("ca-certificates",[20130119,1]),("ca-certificates-java",[20120608,1]),("cackey",[0,6,8,1]),("cairo",[1,12,12,2]),("cairo-perl",[1,82,2]),("caps",[0,9,6,1]),("cdparanoia",[10,2,4]),("cdrdao",[1,2,3,6]),("cdrkit",[1,1,11,2]),("chromium",[24,0,1312,70,1]),("chromium-pepper-flash",[11,6,602,167,1]),("cifs-utils",[5,9,1]),("cloog",[0,18,0,1])}
```

This has been cut down. I can parse it out manually (which would more then likely a pain). Is there some directly to start with this and get an object?

Or since Aura was written in haskell should I just use haskell?

Comment: Just modify aura to save in JSON if you are wanting the save format to be readable by multiple programs in different languages.

Comment: Umm...makes sense. Now I need to figure out how to do that *runs away*. I'll let you know soon. =)

Comment: It's not so bad, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the best thing is to make aura save in a JSON format instead of using the `Show` and `Read` instances.  This might not be any easier than making a one-off parser in Python but it will be a more lasting community change. EDIT: If it isn't obvious, my opinion is it would be truly best to just use Haskell so all you need to do is `fmap read (readFile path)` to parse, but I'm accustom to that not being a practical option for many programmers with a short time-line.

Step 1: Get the aura code

```
git clone https://github.com/fosskers/aura.git
cd aura
```

Step 2: Find where it serealizes something named `PkgState`:

```
grep 'writeFile' * -R
```

Step 3: modify the format (which is currently using `show`) to using JSON via the aeson package:

```
+{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
+import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BL
+ import Data.Aeson
...
- liftIO $ writeFile filename (show state)
+ liftIO $ BL.writeFile filename (encode state)
```

Step 4: Step 3 really isn't done, we need `ToJSON` instances for that call to `encode` to work.

```
+{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
+ import Data.Aeson
+ instance ToJSON PkgState of
+     toJSON (PkgState t p) = object [ "timeOf" .= t, "pkgsOf" .= p ]
```

and in `Aura/Time.hs`:

```
+ {-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-} 
...    
+ import Data.Aeson
...
+ instance ToJSON SimpleTime of
+      toJSON (SimpleTime y m d h n) = object [ "yearOf"   .= y
+                                            , "monthOf"  .= fromEnum m
+                                            , "dayOf"    .= d
+                                            , "hourOf"   .= h
+                                            , "minuteOf" .= n
+                                            ]
```

Step 5: To make this build we need to add the aeson package to the `build-deps` in `aura.cabal`.

Step 6: This might work as is for your purposes, but it would be best to make aura able to load files that were JSON encoded:

```
-import Data.Maybe      (mapMaybe)
+import Data.Maybe      (mapMaybe, fromMaybe)
+import Control.Applicative
+import Control.Monad

...

+instance ToJSON PkgState where
+    toJSON (PkgState t p) = object [ "timeOf" .= t, "pkgsOf" .= p ]
+
+instance FromJSON PkgState where
+    parseJSON (Object v) = PkgState <$> v .: "timeOf" <*> v .: "pkgsOf"
+    parseJSON _ = mzero
+

...

-readState name = liftIO (read `liftM` readFile (stateCache </> name))
-
+readState name = liftIO ((fromMaybe err . decode) `liftM` BL.readFile (stateCache </> name))
+  where err = error "Package State unrecognized"
```

and again in `Aura/Time.hs`

```
+
+instance FromJSON SimpleTime where
+    parseJSON (Object v) = SimpleTime <$> v .: "yearOf"
+                                      <*> (toEnum `fmap` (v .: "monthOf"))
+                                      <*> v .: "dayOf"
+                                      <*> v .: "hourOf"
+                                      <*> v .: "minuteOf"
+
```

I'll leave the python decoding of this JSON object to you.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look at doing this. I am not familiar with haskell and this is really just learning for me. Hopefully I will get a chance to set this up in the next day or so to see if this will work for my needs.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to do anything ... life got in the way but I am going to post this on to the github for the project. Edit: accepted your answer since this seems very doable and posted over on the aura github site as well.

Comment: @framusdiu That's great!  Glad you found the post useful.  Feel free to steal all the code you'd like.